# how to enable/disable a dropdown based on value in another dropdown in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jquery

I want to enable/disable a dropdown field based on the value of other dropdown field in the sharepoint 2013 form.I know that it is possible using jquery but i dont know how to write? help me to get the correct code.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose the id of two dropdown controls you have is "ddl1" and "ddl2". So the code snippet for your requirement will be

```
$(function() {
            $("#ddl1").change(function() {
                if ($(this).val() == "<yourValue>") {
                    $("#ddl2").prop("disabled", true);
                }
                else
                    $("#ddl2").prop("disabled", false);
            });
        });
```

The above code will disable the "ddl2" dropdown on select of a particular value in first dropdown. And will enable it if you select another value.
Make sure you have included jquery reference and assigned id's to your fields.

Comment: You should use .prop() for disabled rather than .attr().

Comment: Almost there. It should be $("#ddl2").prop("disabled", true); Properties are binary: they are either on or off, thus true or false. As of jQuery 1.6, you can't use .attr(). See: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript, if you want to do it in client side.

```
function DisableDropdown(id1){
    var elementID;
    elementID = document.getElementById(id1);
    elementID.disabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

on selecting any values from dropdown1 it will disable dropdown2 and vice versa.

```
$(function() {
            $("#dropdown1").change(function() {
                 $("#dropdown2").prop("disabled", true);
            });
           $("#dropdown2").change(function() {
                 $("#dropdown1").prop("disabled", true);    
            });
        });
```